# PHP: readdir to scandir?

Tags: php, readdir, scandir

i wonder how i can transform exactly the following piece of code to `scandir` instead of `readdir`?

```
$path = 'files';

//shuffle files
$count = 0;
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    $retval = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != '.DS_Store' &&
          $file != 'Thumbs.db') {
            $retval[$count] = $file;
            $count = $count + 1;
            } else {
            //no proper file
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
shuffle($retval);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scandir` returns, [quoting](http://fr.php.net/scandir) :

> Returns an array of filenames on
> success, or FALSE on failure.

Which means you'll get the full list of files in a directory -- and can then filter those, using either a custom-made loop with `foreach`, or some filtering function like [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Not tested, but I suppose something like this should to the trick :

```
$path = 'files';
if (($retval = scandir($path)) !== false) {
    $retval = array_filter($retval, 'filter_files');
    shuffle($retval);
}


function filter_files($file) {
    return ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != '.DS_Store' && $file != 'Thumbs.db');
}
```

Basically, here :

- First, you get the list of files, using `scandir`
- Then, you filter out the ones you dn't want, using `array_filter` and a custom filtering function

  - Note : this custom filtering function could have been written using an anonymous function, with PHP >= 5.3
- And, finally, you `shuffle` the resulting array.

Comment: Much much after the fact, but this is the basic approach that I used, except for the callback I used an in_array match instead of multiple tests.   `function cleanDirectoryList( $file )
{
    $disallowed = array(
        '.',
        '..',
        '.DS_Store',
        'Thumbs.db'
    );

    return !in_array( $file, $disallowed );
}` **fail - can't format a comment :(**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do that, here's a much more concise solution though:

```
$path = 'files';
$files = array();
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot() || $fileInfo->getFilename() == 'Thumbs.db') continue;
    $files[] = $fileInfo->getFilename();
}
shuffle($files);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get started with such problems always consult the PHP manual and read the comments, it's always very helpful. It states that `scandir` returns an array, so you can walk through it with [`foreach`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

In order to be able to delete some entries of the array, here's an example with `for`:

```
$exclude = array( ".", "..", ".DS_Store", "Thumbs.db" );
if( ($dir = scandir($path)) !== false ) {
    for( $i=0; $i<count($dir); $i++ ) {
        if( in_array($dir[$i], $exclude) )
            unset( $dir[$i] );
    }
}

$retval = array_values( $dir );
```

Also have a look at the [SPL iterators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) PHP provides, especially `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and `DirectoryIterator`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little function to scan a directory without getting the annoying files.

```
function cleanscandir ($dir) {
  $list = [];
  $junk = array('.', '..', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store');
  if (($rawList = scandir($dir)) !== false) {
    foreach (array_diff($rawList, $junk) as $value) {
      $list[] = $value;
    }
    return $list;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Outputs an array or false just like `scandir` does